# Expressing a block matrix using Kronecker product

Tags: matrices, block-matrices

Let $A=[a_{ij}]$ be an $m \times m$ matrix  and $B$ be a $m n \times m n$ block diagonal matrix with $n \times n$ diagonal blocks $B_1, B_2, \ldots, B_m$. I want to express the following block matrix

$$\begin{bmatrix}
a_{11} B_1 & a_{12}B_1 & \cdots & a_{1m} B_1 \\
a_{21} B_2 & a_{22}B_2 & \cdots & a_{2m} B_2 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
a_{m1} B_m & a_{m2}B_m & \cdots & a_{mm} B_m \\
\end{bmatrix}$$

in a compact form, possibly in one shot using Kronecker products. Is it possible?

Comment: That matrix equals $B(A \otimes I)$.